# Mis-alignment in itemize environment

Tags: itemize

I'm getting an unexpected left-alignment result with what I think is a simple itemize environment -- haven't had any issues like this before. Here is the code:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\item[(i)] Some text; \vspace{4pt}

\item[(ii)] Some text \vspace{4pt}

\item[(iii)]If $B_1, B_2 \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $(B_1 \cap B_2) = \emptyset$, then\\ \vspace{3pt}
\hspace{2cm} $P_X(B_1 \cup B_2) = P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2)$:\\ \vspace{3pt}
Since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint their pre-images in $\Omega$ will be disjoint and by the 
$\sigma$-additivity of $P$ on $\mathcal{A}$ we have that,\\ \vspace{3pt}
$P(X^{-1}(B_1 \cup B_2)) = P(X^{-1}(B_1)) + P(X^{-1}(B_2))\\ \vspace{3pt}
\hspace{2cm}  = P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2)$. \\ 
\end{itemize}
```

The problem is with the third item. When the text beginning `Since' (following the line break) wraps it appears to align to the left of the start of the rest of the elements. I don't think the problem is with the line break because that has note caused issues before for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use display math. I see no reason for so many `\vspace` instructions. Let TeX do the alignments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
\item[(i)] Some text;

\item[(ii)] Some text

\item[(iii)] If $B_1, B_2 \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with 
  $(B_1 \cap B_2) = \emptyset$, then
  \[
    P_X(B_1 \cup B_2) = P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2)
  \]
  Since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint their pre-images in $\Omega$ will be disjoint 
  and by the $\sigma$-additivity of $P$ on $\mathcal{A}$ we have that
  \begin{align*}
    P(X^{-1}(B_1 \cup B_2)) &= P(X^{-1}(B_1)) + P(X^{-1}(B_2))\\
    &= P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2).
  \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `enumitem` in order to avoid manual numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Some text;

\item Some text

\item If $B_1, B_2 \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with 
  $(B_1 \cap B_2) = \emptyset$, then
  \[
    P_X(B_1 \cup B_2) = P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2)
  \]
  Since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint their pre-images in $\Omega$ will be disjoint 
  and by the $\sigma$-additivity of $P$ on $\mathcal{A}$ we have that
  \begin{align*}
    P(X^{-1}(B_1 \cup B_2)) &= P(X^{-1}(B_1)) + P(X^{-1}(B_2))\\
    &= P_X(B_1) + P_X(B_2).
  \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. The \vspace(s) are to compensate for poor eyesight. TeX's spacing is okay (for me) for regular text, but I find it difficult to read when math is involved. AMD is a real pain in the butt ...

Comment: I should have noted in my comment that items (i) and (ii) are all math in my document, but since they were not the problem I opted to put plain text in them for the purpose of the question.

Comment: @TonyK `\linespread{1.2}` in the preamble would space out lines.

Comment: Well that's just nifty. Thank you